# Woocommerce pre_get_posts and tax_query not working as expected

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Having wasted 3 hours trying to find out why my code doesn't work, I've come here to ask for your help. My goal is to use the pre_get_posts filter in order to overload the query during a search, below my code :

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'filter_search', 10, 2);
function filter_search($query) {
    // query only when search from front-end
    if ( !$query->is_admin && $query->is_search) { 
         $tax_query = array(
            array(
               'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
               'field' => 'term_id',
               'terms' => array(424),
               'operator' => 'IN'
            )
         );
         $query->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
         $query->set('post_type', 'product');
         $query->set('post_status', 'publish');
    }
    return $query;
}
```

When executing search, results is empty, or I have data in the database attached to sub term with id 424 :

```
- fruits (parent term) with id 3 (10 posts attached)
  -- apples (sub term) with id 424 (3 posts attached)
  -- ...
```

Could you explain me please what i doing wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems working fine. Can you please check if there is any other plugin conflict?
Also, check for if your theme/plugin use "pre_get_posts" filter twice?

Or you also try below code:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'filter_search', 10, 1);
function filter_search($query) {
    // query only when search from front-end
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_search) { 
         $tax_query = array(
            array(
               'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
               'field' => 'term_id',
               'terms' => array(424),
               'operator' => 'IN'
            )
         );
         $query->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
         $query->set('post_type', 'product');
         $query->set('post_status', 'publish');
    }
}
```

Or try this code with any default theme. It should work fine.